# Issue with calculator program

Tags: java

I have had some problems with my calculator that I recently have created.
I don't know quite what is wrong, and what I have to do, so I hope to get some help.

```
public class calcclass {

public static void main(String []args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberone;
    System.out.print("Type in a number : ");
    numberone = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Type in another number : ");
    int numbertwo = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Do you wish to 1(+), 2(-), 3(*), 4(/) : ");
    int Answer = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    int Sum;
    if (( Answer == '1'))
    {
        System.out.println("PLUS");
        Sum = numberone + numbertwo;
        System.out.println("The answer is : " + Sum);
    }
    if (( Answer == '2'))
    {
        System.out.println("MINUS");
        Sum = numberone - numbertwo;
        System.out.println("The answer is : " + Sum);
    }
    if (( Answer == '3'))
    {
        System.out.println("GONGE");
        Sum = numberone * numbertwo;
        System.out.println("The answer is : " + Sum);
    }
    if (( Answer == '4' ))
    {
        System.out.println("DELE");
        Sum = numberone / numbertwo;
        System.out.println("The answer is : " + Sum);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can also try the `switch`-statement instead of all those `if`'s.

Comment: You've put single quotes around the numbers i.e. '1'; this makes '1' a char, not an int. So when you compare the char with an int, you are most likely to get false.

Comment: What exactly doesnt work? What is the Problem

Comment: Suggestion: Go the extra mile and prompt the user to enter the expression and parse/evaluate it for them. Also don't be scared to `System.out.println("\nThe Rest of your output.");`; `System.out.println("");`'s kinda silly IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

`if (( Answer == '1'))` should be `if (( Answer == 1))`

Why? `Answer` is an `int`, not a `char`.

Your `if` is never satisfied because when you do `if(Answer == '1')` you are actually comparing `Answer` with the [decimal value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the character `'1'`.

**Recommendations**:

1. Follow [Java Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) - Name variables with lowercase at beginning.
2. `if((Answer == 1))` can be written `if(Answer == 1)`.
3. Use [`switch-case`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) instead of `if` in these cases.
4. Name `sum` something else, as it's not always "sum" operation. Possible name: `result`.

Comment: Also keep your variable names decent. The result of the calculation isn't always a 'sum' of numbers. Better name it 'calculationResult' or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing Answer to character values of 1, 2, 3, 4. For example :

```
System.out.println((int) '1');
```

Would print 49;

Use this instead, without quotes around numbers:

```
if ((Answer == 1)) {
        System.out.println("PLUS");
        Sum = numberone + numbertwo;
        System.out.println("The answer is : " + Sum);
    }
    if ((Answer == 2)) {
        System.out.println("MINUS");
        Sum = numberone - numbertwo;
        System.out.println("The answer is : " + Sum);
    }
    if ((Answer == 3)) {
        System.out.println("GONGE");
        Sum = numberone * numbertwo;
        System.out.println("The answer is : " + Sum);
    }
    if ((Answer == 4)) {
        System.out.println("DELE");
        Sum = numberone / numbertwo;
        System.out.println("The answer is : " + Sum);
    }
```